# Trouble getting textbox value from view to controller in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I'm still a beginner in ASP.NET MVC. I have a project that I am working on right now with two views and 1 controller. 1 scan page, 1 data entry page and 1 controller called `LprController`.

So on the data entry cshtml I have the button that I'm trying to get the data from called lotnoTBX.

```
div class="col-md-4 col-sm-offset-3">
    <img src="~/Images/Capture.PNG" class="media-object center-block"/>
    <div class="block-main col-sm-8 col-sm-offset-4">
        <h2>Scan Lot</h2>
        <input id="lotnoTBX"/>
        <div class="container-fluid row">
            <button id="enterBtn" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-group-lg" style="margin-top:5px;" onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("DataEntry", "Lpr")'">Enter</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Then on the controller page things are a bit confusing. I'm not sure where to save or how to save the lotnoTBX data. Basically I'm using a webservice to get a query from the result of the textbox and post it to the dataentry page using Models.

```
    public ActionResult ScanPage(FormCollection form)
    { 
        string lotno = form["lotnoTBX"];
        Session["lotno"] = lotno;
        return View();
    } 
    public ActionResult DataEntry()
    {
        FCoai.FCWCFT.PCSInterfaceClient client = new FCWCFT.PCSInterfaceClient("BasicHttpBinding_IPCSInterface1");
        FCoai.FCWCFT.PCSResult x = client.getCurrentLotDetail(Session["lotno"].ToString());
        return View();
    }
```

Then here's the data entry page where I'm trying to post the model's in the cshtml.

```
    <table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th class="table-active">OP</th>
                <th class="table-active">Lotno</th>
                <th class="table-active">Itemcode</th>
                <th class="table-active">Marking</th>
                <th class="table-active">Output</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td @Model.op></td>
                <td @Model.lotno></td>
                <td @Model.itemCode></td>
                <td @Model.marking></td>
                <td @Model.output></td>
            </tr>
        </thead>
    </table>
```

*edit I missed out one actionresult which might have been confusing for some people
Please help.

Comment: You need to create a model class and pass it in to the controller method.  The controller method should have model parameter.  Also you need to use the `name` attribute not  just `id` in your HTML. The `id` attribute does not cause data to be posted.

Comment: Could anyone help me with this question, maybe with an example. Sorry, I'm just really having troubles even getting the textbox value to return after submitting the enter btn.

Answer (score 0):

So I managed to get the textbox values to return. It turns out I had to use a form and a model as a parameter in the controller in order to do so.

Here's the scan lot cshtml

```
        <h2>Scan Lot</h2>
        @using (Html.BeginForm("ScanPage"))
        {
            @Html.TextBoxFor(Model => Model.lotno)
            <input type="submit" value="Enter"/>
        }
```

And here are the controllers

```
        public ActionResult ScanPage()
        { 
            return View();
        }  
        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult ScanPage(FCoai.FCWCFT.PCSResult pCS)
        {
            string lotno = pCS.lotno;
            Session["lotno"] = lotno;
            return RedirectToAction("DataEntry", "Lpr");
        }
        public ActionResult DataEntry()
        {
            FCoai.FCWCFT.PCSInterfaceClient client = new FCWCFT.PCSInterfaceClient("BasicHttpBinding_IPCSInterface1");
            FCoai.FCWCFT.PCSResult x = client.getCurrentLotDetail(TempData["lotno"].ToString());
            //Passing data from controller to view
            ViewData["Lot"] = x;
            return View();
        }
```

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <table>
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th class="table-active">OP</th>
                    <th class="table-active">Lotno</th>
                    <th class="table-active">Itemcode</th>
                    <th class="table-active">Marking</th>
                    <th class="table-active">Routing</th>
                </tr> 
                <tr>
                    @{ 
                        //This is how display data from view to controller
                        var lot = (FCoai.FCWCFT.PCSResult)ViewData["Lot"];
                    }
                    <td>@lot.op</td>
                    <td>@lot.lotno</td>
                    <td>@lot.itemCode</td>
                    <td>@lot.markLow</td>
                    <td>@lot.rout</td>
                </tr>
            </thead>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

Edit here's my final answer.

Even though I have managed to find the answer to my own question I would appreciate if you guys could give tips on conventions or otherwise that I could have missed out on.